# How many monster cards / what is the bonus value in the Alvin and Dexter Ticket to Ride expansion

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-alvin-and-dexter

The [Alvin and Dexter](http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/alvin-dexter/) expansion looks like an interesting one, and one you could quite easily do yourself.  To that end, how many cards of each type of monster do you get in the expansion pack and what is the value of the bonuses for each monster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 40 cards (20 for each figure) and the bonus cards are worth 15 points each.

I would strongly urge you to buy the expansion yourself though - it's not all that expensive really, Days of Wonder games always have above averagely beautiful components, and games designers need to eat too!

Comment: I agree, in my defence I think Days of Wonder have done well enough from spreading the word about their games to a number of groups of people: so much so I should be on commission.  I am sure if we try it out and like it I well get the official expansion.